# How to normalize overflowed state in range asymmetric numeral systems?

Tags: compression, lossless-compression

The encoded message contains negative integers. Also the buffer of the `BitWriter` doesn't change.

ChatGPT helped me to fix errors regarding operator precedence.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RansEncoder {
    private final int[] symbolFrequencies;
    private final int totalFrequency;
    private final int[] cumulativeDistributionFunction;
    private final int numberOfQuantizationBits;
    private final int numberOfNormalizationBits;
    private final int numberOfBitsToReadAndWrite;
    private int state;
    public RansEncoder(int numberOfQuantizationBits, int numberOfNormalizationBits, int numberOfBitsToReadAndWrite, int[] symbolFrequencies) {
        this.numberOfQuantizationBits = numberOfQuantizationBits;
        this.numberOfNormalizationBits = numberOfNormalizationBits;
        this.numberOfBitsToReadAndWrite = numberOfBitsToReadAndWrite;
        this.totalFrequency = 1 << numberOfQuantizationBits;
        this.symbolFrequencies = quantizeSymbolFrequencies(symbolFrequencies);
        this.cumulativeDistributionFunction = getCumulativeDistributionFunction();
        this.state = 1 << numberOfNormalizationBits;
    }
    private int[] quantizeSymbolFrequencies(int[] symbolFrequencies) {
        final int totalFrequencyBeforeQuantization = Arrays.stream(symbolFrequencies).sum();
        return Arrays.stream(symbolFrequencies)
                .mapToDouble(Double::valueOf)
                .map(symbolFrequency -> symbolFrequency / totalFrequencyBeforeQuantization)
                .map(symbolProbability -> symbolProbability * totalFrequency)
                .mapToLong(Math::round)
                .mapToInt(Math::toIntExact).toArray();
    }

    private int[] getCumulativeDistributionFunction() {
        int[] cumulativeDistributionFunction = new int[symbolFrequencies.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < symbolFrequencies.length + 1; i++) {
            cumulativeDistributionFunction[i] = Arrays.stream(symbolFrequencies).limit(i).sum();
        }
        return cumulativeDistributionFunction;
    }
    public void write(int symbol, BitWriter writer) {
        normalizeOverflowedStateByWritingBits(symbol, writer);
        encode(symbol);
    }

    private void normalizeOverflowedStateByWritingBits(int symbol, BitWriter writer) {
        while (state >= symbolFrequencies[symbol] << numberOfNormalizationBits) {
            writer.writeBits(state & ((1 << numberOfBitsToReadAndWrite) - 1), numberOfBitsToReadAndWrite);
            state >>= numberOfBitsToReadAndWrite;
        }
    }

    private void encode(int symbol) {
        int nextState = getNextState(symbol);
        state = nextState;
    }

    private int getNextState(int symbol) {
        int nextState = (Math.floorDiv(state, symbolFrequencies[symbol]) << numberOfQuantizationBits) + cumulativeDistributionFunction[symbol] + state % symbolFrequencies[symbol];
        return nextState;
    }
}
```

The utility classes can be found [here](https://github.com/lichess-org/compression/blob/master/src/main/java/IntArrayList.java) and [here](https://github.com/lichess-org/compression/blob/master/src/main/java/BitWriter.java). I don't think they cause the issue because they are used in a big open source project.

A potential error could be the initialization of the `state` or the implementation of the `normalizeOverflowedStateByWritingBits` method.

The test uses 8, 16, 8 for the number of quantization, normalization and read/write bits. The symbolFrequencies are `{5000, 2000, 2000, 1000}` and the message to be encoded is an array consisting of 4000 random integers between 0 and 4 exclusive.

I used [this](https://kedartatwawadi.github.io/post--ANS/) implementation as a reference.